# How to extract demojized emojis from string in Python

Tags: python

I'm using the "emoji" library to emojize and demojize strings to store them as text in a DB. It works fine, but now I want to "clean" a string so it only contains the emojis in it.

So, the string "TEXTOTHER TEXT" is stored in the database as

```
:meat_on_bone:TEXT:bread::meat_on_bone:OTHER TEXT
```

I'd like to know how can I work on the string to get only

```
:meat_on_bone::bread::meat_on_bone:
```

I can think of ways of working on the string, such as going through it looking for when ':' starts and start counting until ':' ends, but I want to know if you can think of a way to make this process more efficient, since I think doing it that way would be very time consuming for the system.

Answer (score 0):

`emoji` library has function `emoji_lis`, that returns all emoji positions in the string. But you have demojized text. So the most efficient way is to emojize-extract-demojize text. These functions work atop of regular expressions so they are pretty fast.

Here is the example:

```
import emoji

# Create demojized text
>>> text = "TEXTOTHER TEXT"
>>> d_text = emoji.demojize(t)
>>> print(d_text)

:meat_on_bone:TEXT:bread::meat_on_bone:OTHER TEXT:bread::bread:
```

```
# Emojize text and get all emojis in it
>>> emojis = emoji.emoji_lis(emoji.emojize(d_text))
# Extract emojis from the structure to the string
>>> print(''.join([d['emoji'] for d in emojis]))
```

It is not really fast, but I think by-hand implementations will be even slower.